# DIsable Left/Right swipe in FlatList or ScrollView

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview

I am trying to use either ScrollView or FlatList to build a swipable carousel. At one step in the swiper, I want to be able to disable scrolling to the next item until another step is completed, but still enable the user to scroll back to the previous screen. How can I disable swiping in a single direction (left/right) while still allowing swipe in the other direction? I have tried to use `onMomentumScrollBegin` and `onScroll` to detect direction and then disable scrolling via the `scrollEnabled` prop, but it is not immediate and causes glitchy behavior

Comment: Did you find any solution?